# C# Trying to compare lines of a textbox and count the quantities for (sometimes duplicate) lines with different quantities

Tags: c#, list, count, compare

I'm still new to programming and have been creating some tools for my associates at work for some redundant tasks.  As I said in the title, I would like to do something like this:

Textbox1 may have:

Apples 3

Apples 4

Oranges 1

I'd like to transfer this over to textbox 2 as this:

Apples 7

Oranges 1

It took into consideration that apples appeared twice and added the total.  The code I have so far is not working`enter code here` and I've been struggling with this for some time:

```
{
            foreach (var lines in textBox1.Lines)
            {

                    string line = lines.TrimEnd();

                    if (line.Length > 0)
                    {
                        int findIndex = line.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1;
                        var qty = (line.Substring(findIndex));
                        int lineInt;

                        try
                        {
                            lineInt = Convert.ToInt32(qty);  //convert whatever the qty detected was, to int32

                            {
                                textBox2.Text += line + lineInt+Environment.NewLine.ToString();
                            }
                        }

                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
```

The result is:

Apples 33

Apples 44

Oranges 11

Which is wrong because I am not removing the initial quantity field at the end, and I am also not totaling the integer value correctly to put on the end, I am just reattaching the quantity on the end.  My end goal is to have a list of many different products/quantities and total them up and see what quantities may have changed from previous orders by doing a set difference/delta or something like that, which I can't do until I can get the right data into textbox2.  The tricky part for me is merging duplicate lines of products but still adding up their combined quantity.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks for reading!

Comment: You should consider using a Hashtable to maintain your count.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

ASPX

```
 <asp:Panel ID=pnl1 runat=server>    
    <asp:TextBox ID=TextBox1 runat=server></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID=TextBox2 runat=server></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID=TextBox3 runat=server></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID=TextBox4 runat=server></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID=TextBox5 runat=server></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID=TextBox6 runat=server></asp:TextBox>
    </asp:Panel>
    <br />
    Total
    <asp:Panel ID=Panel1 runat=server>    

    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Button ID=btn runat=server Text=Total onclick="btn_Click" />
```

CS. Side

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> obj = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            foreach (Control cn in pnl1.Controls)
            {
                if (cn.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                {
                    if (((TextBox)cn).Text.Trim() != "")
                    {
                        string[] spValue = ((TextBox)cn).Text.Split(' ');

                        if (obj.ContainsKey(spValue[0]))
                        {
                            obj[spValue[0]] = obj[spValue[0]] + Convert.ToInt32(spValue[1]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            obj.Add(spValue[0], Convert.ToInt32(spValue[1]));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (string k in obj.Keys)
            {
                TextBox tx = new TextBox();
                tx.Text = k + " " + obj[k].ToString();
                pnl1.Controls.Add(tx);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string previousLine = "";
        foreach (var lines in textBox1.Lines) 
        { 
                string line = lines.TrimEnd(); 
                if (line.Length > 0 && previousLine != "") 
                { 
                    int findIndex = line.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1;
                    //check to ensure the item in this line is equal to the item in the previous line 
                    if(line.substring(0, findIndex - 2) == previousLine.substring(0, findIndex - 2))
                    {
                        var qty = (line.Substring(findIndex)); 
                        int lineInt; 

                        try 
                        {
                            lineInt = Convert.ToInt32(qty);  //convert whatever the qty detected was, to int32 
                            {
                                int previousStringNum = Int32.TryParse(previousLine.Substring(previousLine.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1)

                                int sumOfLineAndPreviousLine = lineInt + previousStringNum;
                                //set the line variable equal to its new value which includes the value from the previous line
                                line = line.substring(0, line.length - 2) + sumOfLineAndPreviousLine.ToString();
                                //textBox2.Text += line + lineInt+Environment.NewLine.ToString();
                                //set the previousLine variable equal to line so that the next pass of the foreach loop if that object equals the object in previousLine, it will continue to add them... 
                                previousLine = line;

                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         //the object in this line is not equal to the object in the previousLine
                         //so append the previousLine to the TextBox2.Text and then
                         //set the previousLine object equal to the current Line so that on the 
                         //next pass of the loop will work correctly
                         textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + previousLine;
                         previousLine = line;

                    }
                }  
        }
```

I believe this may achieve what you want, although it is rather limited. This assumes all of the objects will only have one digit.  The code will need to be altered to handle double digit numbers etc.